# Pnp transistor bypass

Tags: pnp, bypass

I am driving a blue led with a pnp transistor as schematic1.I am trying to bypass the transistor without removing it as schematic2.Is it OK?

[image: schematic1]
Schematic1
[image: schematic2]
Schematic2

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do like Schematic 2. The LED will light till the battery wears down.

Comment: What about the transistor?

Comment: If only one leg of the transistor is connected and the rest is hanging in the air it does nothing. You could clip it out if you wanted to.

Comment: When measuring voltage on emitter or base pin with multimeter,why am i reading voltage on these pins?

Comment: Because when you connect the meter to those parts that are hanging in mid air you are changing the circuit. Your meter is not a purely passive device and it adds some resistance according to its input impedance. That causes some current to flow leaking through the transistor and/or the resistor.

Comment: If so, is it impossible to see practically if voltage available on pins which are hanging in mid air?

Comment: I do not know about you but I cannot "see voltage". I have to measure it. In your case if you used a meter with near infinite input impedance you would disturb the circuit very little and you would read some voltage relative to another part of the circuit. All would depend upon the meter resistance and the leakage current characteristic of the hanging components. With the infinite impedance meter that leakage current would be extremely small and so next to no voltage drop across many parts of the hanging circuit. If the other probe were at the minus of the battery you would (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) measure close to the battery voltage unless a certain junction in the transistor was forward biased at the small leakage current then you might measure something below the battery voltage.